# numpy (n, m) and (n, k) to (n, m, k)

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, tensor

Let `x` be a `np.array` of shape `(n, m)`.

Let `y` be a `np.array` of shape `(n, k)`.

What is the right way of computing the tensor `z` of shape `(n, m, k)` such that

```
for all i in [0, n - 1]
z[i] = np.dot(x[i][:, np.newaxis], y[i][np.newaxis, :])
```

?

In other words, each pair of rows `(x_i, y_i)` gives one matrix of shape `(m, k)`.

I looked at `np.tensordot` but after many trials, I can't find the right value for its `axes` argument. I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Does `x[:,:, np.newaxis] * y[:, np.newaxis, :]` do the job?  Since the `dot` sum axis is size 1, there's no need for `dot` or `matmul`.  Just use element wise multiplication with broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `np.matmul(x[:, :, None], y[:, None, :])` did the trick.

From `numpy.matmul`'s documentation:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

which is exactly what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.einsum()` like this:

```
z = np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', x, y)
```

---

From a quick test, this is also faster than the `np.matmul()`-based approach (except than for very small inputs):

```
import numpy as np


x = np.random.randint(1, 100, (2, 3))
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, (2, 4))

%timeit np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', x, y)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.14 µs per loop
%timeit np.matmul(x[:, :, None], y[:, None, :])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2,07 µs per loop


x = np.random.randint(1, 100, (20, 30))
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, (20, 40))

%timeit np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', x, y)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 32.1 µs per loop
%timeit np.matmul(x[:, :, None], y[:, None, :])
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 76.8 µs per loop


x = np.random.randint(1, 100, (200, 300))
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, (200, 400))

%timeit np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', x, y)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 48.7 ms per loop
%timeit np.matmul(x[:, :, None], y[:, None, :])
# 10 loops, best of 3: 68.2 ms per loop
```

---

The application of `np.dot()` to the broadcastable views like the following:

```
np.dot(x[:, :, None], y[:, None, :])
```

would not work (it will not even get to the right shape).

(EDITED)

Comment: thanks! i'm always reluctant to use this `np.einsum` function because of its odd string argument which is hard to make sense of. i like to define everything as raw numpy operations with broadcasting rather than using (what i find to be) an obscurely string-defined operation. but thanks, this adds to the discussion

Comment: @tgy I also need some time to think about `np.einsum()` first argument in the implicit form or if it contains ellipsis, but I find this use-case quite straightforward: it basically follows the input and output shapes. Also, it seems to be faster than the `np.matmul()` approach.